# Generating random number without using built-in functions

Tags: java, c#, c++, vb.net, vb6

Am on generating snippets for built-in functions to know how they are executed, and is a part of my research also. i successfully completed **some string handling functions,split, substring,reverse etc..** but i stuck in random numbers how they ware generated? how the `RND` or `Random` functions are work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up pseudo-random number generation in your favourite algorithms textbook.  Popular examples include linear-feedback shift registers, multiply-with-carry, and the Mersenne Twister.

Comment: *"Thanks in advance for participating in this dicussion"* - StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum ....

Comment: There are many ways to generate pseudo-random or (true) random numbers.  Please read a textbook, or wikipedia, or something.  And if you want know how Java random number generators work, you can read the source code.  Google will find it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular current algorithm is probably the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), pseudo-code in the Wikipedia article (and there are many implementations available from Google).

Another well known algorithm is [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) which has a proof that reduces its' security to the computational difficulty of computing modular square roots, a problem whose difficulty is assumed to be equivalent to factoring. However Blum Blum Shub is very slow.

Finally, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pseudorandom_number_generators) is a large list of additional pseudo-random number generators. Which algorithm a particular language uses varies.

Comment: "algorthm ...varies" is not true for Java. See javadoc in java.util.Random, method next.

Comment: @Laune but c++ may or may not use a different algorithm. In between those words you quoted were "a particular language uses". Also, I could write a new prng in java.

Comment: Pardon me, but the poster added tags for a selection of languages, and Java is one of them. See this quote from the javadoc: "Java implementations must use all the algorithms shown here for the class Random, for the sake of absolute portability of Java code." - Kindly note that I commented "not true *for Java*" (and not just "not true").

Comment: @laune yes it does. But SecureRandom, and Math.rand() are alternatives in java. Not really my point.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two algorithms that I've used most often in some of my projects:

**1.Uniform distributed numbers in range between 0 and 1**

`result = getRidOfIntegerPart(A * prevResult)`

Where **A** is a seed.

Possible implementation(C++):

```
int main() 
{
    double A = 12.2345; //seed
    double prevResult = 1; //You can assign any value here
    double result;
    double intPart;

    //This will give you 10 uniform distributed numbers
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        double r = A * prevResult;

        result = modf(r, &intPart); // To get rid of integer part

        prevResult = result;

        cout<<"result "<<i<<" = "<<result<<endl;
    }
}
```

**2. Normal(Gauss) distribution**

Here's an original formula:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

But I'm using a bit different simplifed formula:

[image: gauss]

It says that new normal distributed number obtained from sum of 12 uniform distributed numbers(`Sj`)

Possible implementation(C++):

```
class RandomNumberGenerator
{
public:
    RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        uniformPrevResult = 1;
        uniformResult = 0;
        uniformIntPart = 0;
    }

    double generateUniformNumber(double seed)
    {
        double r = seed * uniformPrevResult;

        uniformResult = modf(r, &uniformIntPart); // To get rid of integer part

        uniformPrevResult = uniformResult;

        return uniformResult;
    }

    double generateNormalNumber(double seed)
    {
        double uniformSum = 0;

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        {
            uniformSum += generateUniformNumber(seed);
        }

        double normalResult = uniformSum - 6;

        return normalResult; // 6 is a magic number
    }

private:
    double uniformPrevResult;
    double uniformResult;
    double uniformIntPart;
};

int main() 
{
    const double seed = 12.2345;

    RandomNumberGenerator rndGen;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        double newNormalNumber = rndGen.generateNormalNumber(seed);

        cout<<"newNormalNumber = "<<newNormalNumber<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 1):

The JAva languages uses the algorithm that is documented in java.util.Random. There it also states that all implementations must use this algorithm

```
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits));
```

**Hence it is not true for Java that "which algorithm a particular language uses varies".**